# Should I radically edit a bad quality question, if I think I can put the question in an acceptable quality state and respect the OP's intent?

Tags: discussion

Earlier this day, I stumbled on a badly phrased, not answerable question.
Since the OP was looking like someone who just had difficulty writing his question, I asked him more details in comment. But the really bad quality of the original question, and the bad quality of the OP's edit lead to the question being closed as "Too Broad".

I too think the question was too broad and was going to leave it as that, but the OP continued to ask me in comments, and I was able to understand what he wanted to do.

After asking him to describe more clearly his need, I saw that his edit couldn't save the question and rewrote the entire question, trying to put the question in a answerable state.

I now wonder if that was the right move, or if I should have continued to push the OP to make his question clearer?

*Note:* I informed the OP of what I did, and explained him why I took the liberty to mass edit his question, and continue to ask him more details about his question. I also informed him that he could rollback my edit if I misunderstood his intention, or if he thought the edit was offensive.

*Note 2*: The OP just thanked me of taking the initiative, but I'd still like to know the community stance on that kind of edit.

Comment: If you are sure you understand the question, go for it! I for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39269019/5) did a pretty big edit on a question too today. Just make sure you don't edit it into a different question and if the question already got answers you have to look out that you don't invalidate them by your edit. Also leaving a comment and explaining what you did here is probably optional, but nice to do.

Comment: Such edits are hard but generally welcome - see my change  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793582/difference-in-array-initialization-with-and-without-new-operator as another example. Note that as [Kendara pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333689/477420) result better be on-topic (possibly duplicate, but definitely not opinion based/too broad/missing MCVE...) for edit to impact SO in positive way.

Comment: The way that you describe what happened, DrakaSAN, what you are doing is asking a question yourself--although one that OP wanted answered--and then letting OP take credit for it.  Assuming it then becomes a good question, it could get upvoted.  That doesn't seem wrong, though it's generous in multiple ways.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't see an issue with this idea in general, provided the editor does not change what the OP is asking and is truly trying to help them reword the question to be clear and on topic. Asking questions in the comments and both nudging the OP to edit and making some edits yourself is a decent way to do this. However, in this specific case, I don't think it really did a lot of good.

Some people have a hard time explaining themselves, some don't have a great grasp of English, and some just don't understand how to write a good question. These problems can make it hard for some users to write a good, clear question.

You did a nice thing, taking the time to try to help the OP get their question on track, make it clear what they wanted to do, and help them learn how to write a good question. However, the question in its current state is still too broad.

"Where do I start" questions are generally not a good fit for the site, as the answer varies, can be long, or there can be a lot of correct answers. The answers will often tend to be opinionated as well, meaning these questions can also be closed as "primarily opinion based."

What the OP really needs to do is take a stab at writing the code, or find a tutorial or book to try to start from, and write a question if they hit problems. Their question then can be more direct, more objective, and less broad.

Comment: TL;DR - It is perfectly fine to unearth a diamond, it is waste of effort to polish turd.

Comment: "Where do I start" often implies not enough research.

Answer (score 6):

Out of pure self-interest we should also think about teaching users to ask good question. After all, close voting, down voting, commenting ... is a lot of work and bad questions decrease the signal to noise. This is not in our interest.

Downvoting and close voting bad questions is probably the most efficient step to education in terms of work required from our side. (medium educational effect, low effort from our side)

If however you have some additional free time and can in the course of a conversation find out what the OP wanted and think that this would make an on topic question, you can educate him to improve the question (this is probably the highest educational effect but requires more time).

However, you should not do the work for them and formulate a good question for them. That in general does not teach a lot. (low educational effect with maximum effort from your side) They might even rely on it.

Some users might learn from a good example of how to ask a question, but I would strongly prefer if they try on their own, even if the result is less good (but they learn more from it and will get better eventually).

**Summary:** I would not have done it but rather urged the person to improve the question and maybe only at the end, went shortly over it, to polish a bit.

If you have free time to educate people here, better discuss with them in comments and try to encourage them to improve their contributions on their own.

Comment: I understand your point, and agree with you. However, the OP was clearly unable to salvage the question alone, which pushed me to try. He still need to add a lot of information on his own, so I didn't do all the work either.